# Open Source (Free) ASP.NET Site Seacrch

Tags: c#, asp.net, search

Does anybody know of an easy to implement site search engine for asp.net? The less complicated the better.

Probably just needs a crawler and backend to store results. Some sort of API to get the search results back would be handy but I can get it straight from the DB as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Dot Lucene](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/) (AKA Lucene.net)

You can find a good sample and explanation in [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/DotLuceneSearch.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Lucene.Net](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/). It is a .Net port of a very mature Java search engine. I've heard very good things about the .Net version.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search in database behind site, Full Text Search can also help.